# PagerSlidingTabStrip indicator light does not change with the page?

Tags: android

It is working for my search activity page but not for my profile activity: The indicator light under the selected tab, do I have to add something
HEre is the code:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

 String[] tabTitles =  {"Completed", "Joined"};
        adapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), profileCompletedFrag, profileJoinedFrag, tabTitles);

//        // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.profilePager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.profileTabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

 /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                if (position == 0) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                    pager.setCurrentItem(0);


                }
                if (position == 1) {
                    currentPage = 1;
                    pager.setCurrentItem(1);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
        /////////////
        tabs.setOnTabReselectedListener(new PagerSlidingTabStrip.OnTabReselectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Tab reselected: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (position == 0) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                     pager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }
                if (position == 1) {
                    currentPage = 1;
                    pager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }
            }
        });
```

He is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profileParentLayout">
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/profileNameLayout"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/profileName"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:text="Bob Marley"/>
   </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/profileImageLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileNameLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:id="@+id/profileImage"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_w"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/editProfileImage"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/profileDetailsLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/profileImageLayout">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profileFollowers"
        android:text="13 followers"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <View android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width = "1dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profileFollowing"
        android:text="45 following"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />

    <View android:id="@+id/separator2"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width = "1dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profilePoints"
        android:text="124 points"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileDetailsLayout">
        <!-- for Tabs -->
        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/profileTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/profilePager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>



    <GridView
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabsLayout"
        android:id="@+id/profileGridView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class TabAdapter  extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    String[] tabTitles =  {"Completed", "Joined"};

    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(fragmentManager);
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return tabTitles[position];
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            return ProfileDataFagment.newInstance(0);
        case 1: 
            return ProfileDataFagment.newInstance(1);
        default:
            break;
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2; // Number of views  
    }


}
```

// Also create ProfileDataFagment and set you data according to your position

Comment: Not sure I understand I have the same listeners attached in both

Comment: There is no need to override the listeners, commnet them and try your code

Comment: If you are using this lib https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip then there is no need to handle listeners by yourself, the librrary itself indecate that you swipe or select new tab and set the indecator, if you override the listeners then you stoped the library listeners, that's why i asked you to comment the listeners code in your activity, to use the library as default, did you do that? please add a screenshot for the tabs while the screen launches, or tell me the indicator appears in the first tab, and not moves when you swipe or not?

Comment: Well the issue is if I do not see when onPageselectedListener then I cannot have different grids shown based on what page is selected

Comment: SO you must set fragment for each tab according to its position in PagerAdapter (in your code you name it TabAdapter), you can do it by make only one fragment and send the position as an argument to set the view you want, i will update my code to help you understand me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77942/discussion-between-yousef-safwat-and-lion789).